# Best way to update trail taken by user in map view android

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-geolocation

I am using a [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) to display the current position of the user. The user is supposed to be able to move around and a blue line corresponding to his/her path will be displayed.

I am using the [getCurrentLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation(int,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken)) function to get the location every 5 secs and then update the path on the map using a [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial#add_a_polyline_to_draw_a_line_on_the_map).

My question is what is the best way (resources wise) to get the location **considering that the MapView is already active and has the location of the device**.

Should I be using -

1. [getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known)
2. [getCurrentLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation(int,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken)) itself
3. [getMyLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation()) (deprecated) that can be called directly on my GoogleMap object

Answer (score 0):

Seems to depend on your specific use case.

> Returns a single current location fix on the device. Unlike getLastLocation() that returns a cached location, this method could cause active location computation on the device. A single fresh location will be returned if the device location can be determined within reasonable time (tens of seconds), otherwise null will be returned.

> This method may return locations that are a few seconds old, but never returns much older locations. This is suitable for foreground applications that need a single fresh current location.

> Background apps calling this method will be throttled under background location limits, so background apps may find the method returns null locations more often.

[link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation(int,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken))